# Get value of li on click using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

This is my first question here, so forgive me is asked incorrectly.
I have an html view:

```
 <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="mysearch">
                        <li><a href="/Home/SearchPlayersRegForm" id="Searchstr" >Registration Number</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/SearchPlayersView" id="LastName">Last Name Only</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/SearchPlayersView" id="FullName">Child's First and Last Name</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/SearchPlayersView" id="Pho">Phone Number</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Searchstr" id="Search" placeholder="Search term...">
                <span class="input-group-btn seach-form">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="PerformSearch(event)" id="Searchstr"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
```

and i want to use a JQuery to find the value in the li

```
function PerformSearch(event) {
alert('I AM HERE')
var btn_name = $(document).attr('class')
var OptionForm = $(document).closest('li').attr('id');
alert(btn_name + " within " + id);};
```

am i doing this completely wrong? I go to the function but I can't get the function to pull the id in the li.

Comment: find value of li on click of a button?get all value of li?

Comment: Yes, you are doing this completely wrong. Among other problems, you're trying to alert the variable `id` when you haven't set it (you set the oddly-named variable `OptionForm`).

Comment: Additionally, your lis don't have an id, the a tags inside them do though  ;)

Comment: Thanks DelightedD0D That helped me!  I feel silly for not catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that use a class.

Then use jquery to check if the class has been clicked, and then use something like data-livalue to get the value of the href which you can pass.

......

in  jquery do as follows:

```
        $('.liclickedclass').click(function(){
        var vref =   $(this).data('livalue')
        alert(vRef)
        # windows.location.href = vref 
        });
```